# Take the sum of the query result as separate data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Etity

```
@Entity
public class DateFMail {

    @Id
    
    private double balance;

    public DateFMail() {
    }

    public DateFMail(double balance) {this.balance = balance;}

    public DateFMail(DateFMail dateFMail) {
    }

    public double getBalance() { return balance;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DateFMail{" +
                "balance=" + balance +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Service

```
public interface DateFMailService {
    List<DateFMail> findAll();
}
```

Impl

@Service
public class DateFMailServiceImpl implements DateFMailService {

```
@Autowired
private DateFMailRepository mailRepository;

@Override
public List<DateFMail> findAll() {
    return mailRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

Repository

@Repository
public interface DateFMailRepository extends JpaRepository<DateFMail, Long> {

```
@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(balance) \n" +
        "      FROM agents", nativeQuery = true)
List<DateFMail> findAll();
```

}

Mail Seder

```
@Service
public class EmailDos {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

     private DateFMailRepository mailRepository;

    String fileDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    String fileDate = (today.minusDays(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM"));
    String fileDate2 = (today.minusMonths(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM"));

    public void sendMailSum(String from, String to, String subject, String body, String fileToAttach) throws SQLException {

            List<DateFMail> list = new ArrayList<>(mailRepository.findAll());
            List<DateFMail> list1 = list.stream()
                    .map(DateFMail::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
       
        System.out.println("sending email...................");
        System.out.println(list1);
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
                mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
                mimeMessage.setText(body);

                FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("C:...xlsx"));
                MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
                helper.setFrom("SomeAddress@gmail.com");
                helper.setTo(InternetAddress.parse("SomeAddress@gmail.com"));  
                helper.setText("Good day!\nIn attachment payments for " + fileDate + " с 12.00-00.00" + "\nAmount for " + fileDate1 + list1);

                helper.addAttachment("...xlsx", file);

                mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
                System.out.println("email Fab was successfully sent.....");
            }
        };

        try {
            mailSender.send(preparator);
        } catch (MailException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Component
public class DateFMailController {

    @Autowired
    private DateFMailService mailService;

    public void saveSum() throws IOException {
        saveExcel(mailService.findAll(), "....xlsx");
    }

    private void saveExcel(List<DateFMail> list, String fileName) throws IOException {

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("ECards");
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

        CellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());
        headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        XSSFFont font = ((XSSFWorkbook) workbook).createFont();
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
        font.setBold(true);
        headerStyle.setFont(font);

        Cell headerCell = header.createCell(0);
        headerCell.setCellValue("Sum");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setWrapText(true);

        int ix_row=2;
        for (DateFMail dateFMail : list) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(ix_row);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(dateFMail.getBalance());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            ix_row++;
        }

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

Save Runer

```
@Component
public class SaveCardsStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ECardController eCardController;
    private DateFMailController controller;
  

//    @Autowired
//    private EmailDos emailDos;

    String fileDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    String fileDate = (today.minusDays(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM"));
    String fileDate2 = (today.minusMonths(1)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM"));

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        eCardController.saveCards();
        controller.saveSum();
    }
}
```

I have corrected my question. I've pasted all the code here that pertains to my question. For starters, I would like to simply output the Query result of the repository to the console. But in the form that I just posted here, I get a NullPointerException error and says that in a part of the code: controller.saveSum (); - controller = null.

Comment: Create a PaymentService class which should contain the method getTotalPayment. 
Inject this class in EmailSend (tip: please change this class name from EmailSend to EmailSender as class names should be noun) class. And then in PaymentService Class you should interact Data Repository class. 
Call this getTotalPayment method from the EmailSend class.

Comment: @Ubaid ur Rehman Created a separate Entity for this, a repository (which works correctly). But when it comes to calling this method, a NullPointerException is thrown

Comment: if Calling  new method from EmailSend causing Null Pointer Exception, then please check if the repository is autowired correctly

Comment: @Ubaid ur Rehman Look here please. I have corrected my question. I'm already trying to at least get the Query result of the repository into the console. But again NullPointerException. (controller.saveSum () - null)

Comment: @Ubaid ur Rehman You were right. I didn't pay attention to @Autowired)). Thanks for the tip! Can you write an answer so that I can close my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a PaymentService class which should contain the method getTotalPayment. Inject this class in EmailSend (tip: please change this class name from EmailSend to EmailSender as class names should be noun) class. And then in PaymentService Class you should interact Data Repository class. Call this getTotalPayment method from the EmailSend class.